# Showing A Timer Result

Tags: c#, timer, textbox

I have instantiated a timer like so:

```
System.Timers.Timer seconds = new System.Timers.Timer();
seconds.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(seconds_Tick);
seconds.Interval = 1;
seconds.Enabled = true; //start timer
```

I have created the tick event like so:

```
private void seconds_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)//source
{
    time++;
}//end clock_Tick()
```

**time** is an integer variable declared in the code.

I try to display the results like so (within a method):

```
txtProcessTime.Text = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(time).ToString();
```

This works great up until the timer runs longer than an hour so I then tried:

```
txtProcessTime.Text = TimeSpan.FromHours(time).ToString();
```

This shows an even more unusual/unexpected result.

I tried a few others but I reckon I'm using the wrong section..

I would like to code a timer that counts taking into consideration, milliseconds, seconds and hours and have the result displayed in a textbox. Can you help?

The timer is displayed in the format 00:00:00
The `TimeSpan.FromHours` issue displayed something along the lines of: 7070:xx:xx (I can't remember what the x's values were).
The `TimeSpan.FromSeconds` once the program has been running longer than an hour showed: 2:xx:xx (I can't remember what the x's values were).

The format is being displayed as mm:ss:milliseconds - Could it be that the minutes converted to single numbers once the 60 minutes has passed?

Comment: "This works great up until the timer runs longer than an hour...". What happens? Do you get an error? "This shows an even more unusual/unexpected result." Again, what is it doing?

Comment: The Interval property of the Timer is not in seconds it is in milliseconds.  Your TimeSpan.FromSeconds call will not yield you a TimeSpan in seconds.

Comment: Check edited question for reply (sorry for ambiguity).
I see where that has caused an issue.

Comment: Why not just - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.elapsed.aspx

Comment: There are lots of things wrong here.  You can't get 1 millisecond.  You cannot get 1000 milliseconds either, the granularity is 1/64 seconds.  You cannot update a textbox from a Elapsed event handler.  Get ahead by using a synchronous timer and recording the start time from DateTime.UtcNow.  When it ticks, subtract that from DateTime.UtcNow again to get elapsed wallclock time.

Answer (score 2):

There is something apparently wrong here: `Interval` is specified in [milliseconds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.interval.aspx), but you set it to `1`. Then, you create the `TimeSpan` using `FromSeconds`.

So if you want an event every second, set it like this:

```
seconds.Interval = 1000;
```

If you still want it every millisecond, then change your `TimeSpan`:

```
txtProcessTime.Text = TimeSpan.FromMilliSeconds(time).ToString()
```

Comment: 1000 milliseconds is a second, however the timer may run for less than a second so I need the intervals to be smaller.. How would I show this?

Comment: @Sayse no worries, someone -1ed for you

Comment: I realised, I believe your answer was correct at the time of posting

Answer (score 2):

Instead of your current approach you may find this more usable, and easily modified for your requirements

`using System.Diagnostics`

```
    Stopwatch sw;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = sw.Elapsed.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: This requires some action (button click in this case) to update the textbox, while OP wants to (I understand) update every second.

Comment: @JuliánUrbano - He could always combine it with his interval timer or data bind ;)

Comment: yep. Weird there isn't some sort of `Elapsed` time in `Timer`